sshd: fatal: Access denied for user nagios by PAM account configuration [preauth]
I usually log in on my machine using two accounts corti and nagios via SSH.
After a reboot, during several hours, I am not able to log in remotely with nagios (the other one works).
In the logs I see:
2024-05-13 15:46:52.105497+0200 0x26470  Default 0x0   12510  0    sshd: fatal: Access denied for user nagios by PAM account configuration [preauth]

After a couple of hours, nagios is able to log in again (no changes on the system)
Now:

As far as I know macOS does not use PAM. The setting is thefore commented-out in sshd-config. Setting it to No or Yes does not solve the problem.
Both users have the permission to log in remotely

Update
Login is now possible (after 3 hours). Nothing was changed on the system:
2024-05-13 16:41:13.320484+0200 0x322c8    Default     0x0  16403  0    sshd: fatal: Access denied for user nagios by PAM account configuration [preauth]
2024-05-13 16:44:35.440979+0200 0x32d69    Default     0x0  16615  0    sshd: fatal: Access denied for user nagios by PAM account configuration [preauth]
2024-05-13 16:45:22.012502+0200 0x33077    Default     0x0. 16682  0    sshd: (libpam.2.dylib) in pam_sm_setcred(): pam_sm_setcred: krb5 user nagios doesn't have a principal
2024-05-13 16:45:22.012595+0200 0x33077    Default     0x0  16682  0    sshd: (libpam.2.dylib) in pam_sm_setcred(): pam_sm_setcred: ntlm user nagios doesn't have a password
2024-05-13 16:45:22.016927+0200 0x3307c    Default     0x0  16684  0    sshd: (libpam.2.dylib) in pam_sm_setcred(): pam_sm_setcred: krb5 user nagios doesn't have a principal

But I get the messages that:

the user does not have a password and
the user does not have a principal


macOS uses Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM) for authentication. The configurations are stored at /etc/pam.d. How were the two local accounts created?

@GrahamMiln Thanks. I'm not really sure (it's 5 years ago) but 'corti' was created during the machine installation process and 'nagios' from the settings panel.
